# How to copy the values of a column of formulas to another column in VB

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy the values a column with formulas in to another column without formulas.

I found this on rows, but nothing on a single column

```
Sub Transfer()
    Dim lngRow      As Long
    Dim lngastRow   As Long
    
    lngLastRow = Sheets("Invoice").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For lngRow = 2 To lngLastRow
        If Len(Sheets("Invoice").Cells(lngRow, "B").Value) > 0 Then
            Call Sheets("Invoice").Cells(lngRow, "B").EntireRow.Copy
            Call Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial(Paste:=xlValues)
        End If
    Next lngRow
End
```

but it is for rows...

Comment: `but it is for rows...` - and a collection of rows from the same column forms... the entire single column.

Answer (score 0):

- If any cells in Col B on Invoice is non-blank, copy its value to Col A on Data
- Please provide the details if this is not what you are looking for.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Transfer()
    Dim lngRow      As Long
    Dim lngLastRow   As Long
    With Sheets("Invoice")
        lngLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For lngRow = 2 To lngLastRow
            If Len(.Cells(lngRow, "B").Value) > 0 Then
                Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Sheets("Data").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = .Cells(lngRow, "B").Value
            End If
        Next lngRow
    End With
End Sub
```

It is recommended to include `Option Explicit` to avoid some coding error. eg. `Dim lngastRow As Long` The variable is different with the variable which is used later (`lngLastRow = Sheets("Invoice")....`).